# Add button in menu, Mac OS X.

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch, menu

*Please*, tell me, how can I add a button in **the top right menu**, where skype, clock and other are located?

Sorry, I can't attach screen because of my reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSStatusBar.  See the documentation at : 
https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html